# python deleting older files that match an unknown pattern (tricky)

Tags: python, regex, linux, algorithm

My server is filling up and I need to automate file deletion. Files generally get added to my server daily but sometimes there are pauses making them bi-weekly and or monthly. They stop coming in for months and then start again, it's unpredictable.

My script needs to delete files that are older than 30 days **but always keep the newest 5 files of any file pattern it finds**. This is the tricky part.

The only predictable thing/pattern about the files is the files always contain a yyyymmddhhmmss timestamp somewhere and some pattern that repeats,
other parts of the file names are not always predictable. If a file has no timestamp I don't want to delete it.

An example directory my have something like this

20121118011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_10342532.zip
20121119011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_102345234.zip
20121120011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_10642224.zip
20121121011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_133464.zip
20121122011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_126434344.zip
20121123011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_12444656.zip
20121124011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_1624444.zip
20121125011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_3464433.zip
randomefilewithnodate.zip
20121119011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_336655.zip
20121120011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_336677.zip
20121121011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_338877.zip
20121122011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_226688.zip
20121123011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_776688.zip
20121124011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_223355.zip
20121125011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_111111.zip

In such a case my script should only be deleting the oldest 3 files of that first pattern
20121118011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_10342532.zip
20121119011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_102345234.zip
20121120011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_10642224.zip

and the oldest 2 files of the second pattern
20121119011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_336655.zip
20121120011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_336677.zip

*this way it keeps 5 newest files and doesn't touch the file with no date*

My problem is I have no way of knowing what exactly will follow yyyymmddhhmmss_
I only know it will be various iterations of yyyymmddhhmmss_something_consistent_random_random or yyyymmddhhmmss_something_consistent_something_consistent_random_random.xyz

So far I've come up with the regex to match if a time stamp exists, but I can't think of how to get my script to be smart enough to detect the rest of the file's pattern and keep 5 days of a pattern.

Any ideas are welcome! The script below is not perfect, *I can fix the small mistakes.*

**I really need help with the keeping 5 newest files part mainly**

Bonus question is the epoc time part.

```
def myCleansingMethod(self, client)

    # Get rid of things older than 30 days
    # 30 days has this many seconds 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
    numberOfSeconds = 2592000
    # establish what the epoc time of the oldest file I want to keep is
    oldestFileThatIWantToKeep = time.time() - numberOfSeconds
    #establish my working directory
    workingDirectory = "/home/files/%s" % (client)
    try:
        files = os.listdir(workingDirectory)
        except:
        print "Could not find directory"
        return

        files.sort()
        for file in files:
            # define Full File Name (path + file)
            fullFileName = "%s/%s" % (workingDirectory, file)
            # make sure the file contains yyyymmddhhmmss
            match = re.search(r'[0-9]{4}(1[0-2]|0[1-9])(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0[1-9])([01]\d|2[0123])([0-5]\d){2}', file)
            if match:
                #get what was matched in the RegEx
                fileTime = match.group()
                #convert fileTime to Epoc time
                fileTimeToEpoc = (fileTime + NOT SURE HOW TO DO THIS PART YET)

                if fileTimeToEpoc < oldestFileThatIWantToKeep AND (CODE THAT MAKES SURE   THERE ARE AT LEAST 5 FILES OF THE SAME PATTERN PRESENT) :
                print "Delete file: %s\t%s" % (fileTimeToEpoc, fullFileName)
                command = "rm -Rf %s" % fullFileName
                print command
                os.system (command)
                else:
                pass  
            else:
            pass
```

Comment: Your main problem is that the files on your server are unpredictable, if possible, you should try to standardize the naming method for the files that go on your server so that you can parse them properly. You could either do this with regular expressions and go crazy. Or you could have some proper server rules and then simply `glob` the files of the patterns you need and sort them using basic python without needing to parse anything crazy.

Comment: Does "5 days" mean that if files are not modified for a year then it should preserve files in the date range: `(year ago - 5 days) .. year ago`?

Comment: I edited the question to read "keep the newest 5 files of any file pattern it finds." 5 days was misleading sorry.

Comment: notice that each file increments by 1 day in the yyyymmddhhmmss portion.

Comment: I wish it were that easy Inbar!

Comment: Are the files always named in this way -  [yyyymmddhhmmss]_A_PATTERN_[random_integer].[extension]? If that is the case, it will be easy to group files by the \_A_PATTERN\_ part, say a dictionary with a key \_A_PATTERN\_ and value list of the filenames. Working your way from there would be easy.

Comment: Can you use operating systems last modified timestamp? Because then you could at least start by finding the five that you will not delete, sequestering them and then work out which other ones need deletion.

Comment: I can't keep a dictionary unfortunately because new files with new patterns could get added at any point.

Comment: aychedee - I can use the created timestamp, but not last modified. But how would that let me group the files by the patterns they have?

Comment: I misread the question, don't worry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a nice task, I made heavy use of functional patterns, mainly from `itertools`. I love using iterators, as they are scalable, even for huge lists, and the functional ideas involved make the code readable and maintainable.

First, import what we need from itertools and datetime:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
from datetime import datetime
```

Get your sample filenames as list:

```
filenames = """20121118011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_10342532.zip
20121119011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_102345234.zip
20121120011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_10642224.zip
20121121011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_133464.zip
20121122011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_126434344.zip
20121123011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_12444656.zip
20121124011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_1624444.zip
20121125011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_3464433.zip
randomefilewithnodate.zip
20121119011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_336655.zip
20121120011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_336677.zip
20121121011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_338877.zip
20121122011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_226688.zip
20121123011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_776688.zip
20121124011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_223355.zip
20121125011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_111111.zip""".split("\n")
```

Some helper functions. Names should be self explaining.

```
def extract_date(s):
    return datetime.strptime(s.split("_")[0], "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

def starts_with_date(s):
    try:
        extract_date(s)
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False
```

The next method you might want to adjust if it doesn't cover all cases - for you sample data, it does.

```
def get_name_root(s):
    return "".join(s.split(".")[0].split("_")[1:-1])

def find_files_to_delete_for_group(group):
    sorted_group = sorted(group, key=extract_date)
    return sorted_group[:-5]
```

Now, the whole routine can be done with some iterating. First, I filter the list of filenames, all those that do not start with a data (in your format) are filtered out. Then, the remaining are grouped by their "name root" (couldn't think of a better name).

```
fn_groups = groupby(
                filter(
                    starts_with_date,
                    filenames),
                get_name_root
            )
```

Now, for each group, I apply a filtering-method (see above) to find all those filenames that do not contain the five newest dates. What is found for each group is `chain`ed, i.e., one iterator is created from multiple lists:

```
fns_to_delete = chain(*[find_files_to_delete_for_group(g) for k, g in fn_groups])
```

Finally, for easily checking the result, I convert the iterator to a list and print it:

```
print list(fns_to_delete)
```

The output of this script is:

```
['20121118011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_10342532.zip', '20121119011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_102345234.zip', '20121120011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_10642224.zip', '20121119011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_336655.zip', '20121120011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_336677.zip']
```

If anything is unclear, just ask.

And here is the whole script, for simple c&p-ing:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
from datetime import datetime

filenames = """20121118011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_10342532.zip
20121119011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_102345234.zip
20121120011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_10642224.zip
20121121011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_133464.zip
20121122011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_126434344.zip
20121123011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_12444656.zip
20121124011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_1624444.zip
20121125011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_3464433.zip
randomefilewithnodate.zip
20121119011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_336655.zip
20121120011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_336677.zip
20121121011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_338877.zip
20121122011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_226688.zip
20121123011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_776688.zip
20121124011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_223355.zip
20121125011335_team2-Paper_Size_Report_111111.zip""".split("\n")

def extract_date(s):
    return datetime.strptime(s.split("_")[0], "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

def starts_with_date(s):
    try:
        extract_date(s)
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False

def get_name_root(s):
    return "".join(s.split(".")[0].split("_")[1:-1])

def find_files_to_delete_for_group(group):
    sorted_group = sorted(group, key=extract_date)
    return sorted_group[:-5]        

fn_groups = groupby(
                filter(
                    starts_with_date,
                    filenames),
                get_name_root
            )

fns_to_delete = chain(*[find_files_to_delete_for_group(g) for k, g in fn_groups])

print list(fns_to_delete)
```

Comment: your answer side-steps the issue of defining `get_name_root()` for a general case of `"yyyymmddhhmmss_something_consistent_random_random or yyyymmddhhmmss_something_consistent_something_consistent_random_random.xyz"` filenames. It is not trivial and it may be ambiguous. Look at [my answer for an example of how it can be handled](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14728052/4279).

Comment: Yes, the OP mentions this, you're right. But not one of the examples matches one of these two patterns! I concentrated on the examples...

Answer (score 1):

The difficult part of what you need to do isn't a coding problem, it's a definition problem, and so it can't be solved just by writing better code :-)

Why is it that `20121125011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_3464433.zip` is part of the same group as `20121118011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_10342532.zip` and `20121119011335_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_102345234.zip`? How have you (as a human) realised that the significant common part is `_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_` and not `_team1-pathway_Truck_Report_Data_1`?

Answer that question (I suspect the answer will involve the words "underscores" and/or "digits"), and you will have a way forwards.

> I only know it will be various iterations of
>   yyyymmddhhmmss_something_consistent_random_random or
>   yyyymmddhhmmss_something_consistent_something_consistent_random_random.xyz

If that's all the possible variation, then I would say you need to look for underscore-surrounded common initial sequences. This works because the random stuff is always at the end, so if you want to include the file extension as significant then you'll have to treat that specially (e.g. move it to the front of the strings you're comparing). If you find several files that have three "words" in common but not four, then you assume that the fourth block is "random" and the three blocks are "consistent". Then you sort all files of that type by date, take the newest five off the list, and delete anything left that's over 30 days old.

The "obvious" way to find those common initial sequences is to sort the file names in lexicographical order of their components *other than the date*. Then files with common initial sequences are adjacent, so you can iterate through the list comparing each file to the current longest run of files-with-a-prefix-in-common.

As you're coding, make sure that if the following case is possible, you handle it correctly:

```
<some_date>_truck1_548372.zip
<some_date>_truck1_847284.zip
<some_date>_truck1_data_4948739.zip
<some_date>_truck1_data_9487203.zip
```

That is, make sure you know whether you're dealing with one group in this case ("truck1"), or two groups, ("truck1" and "truck1_data"). It matters because you might want to exclude any `truck1_data` files from the requirement to keep 5 `truck1` files.

---

A different approach:

- find all files more than 30 days old (e.g. `<some_date>_truck1_57349.zip`) and sort them from oldest to newest
- for each file seek "permission" to delete it as follows:

  - Remove the date from the start of the filename
  - Search for all files (not just those over 30 days old) that, ignoring their own date, have a common initial underscore-surrounded substring with this file (so here we find the `truck1` files and the `truck1_data` files)
  - Having found those files, find the longest substring shared by at least two of them (`truck1_data`)
  - If the target file doesn't share that substring, remove all files with the common substring from the set and repeat the previous step (now we're down to just the `truck1` files)
  - Once the target file shares the substring, count them. Delete the target file if there are at least 5.

As stated this is needlessly slow but I think it illustrates the point simply. At the last step you can actually delete all but 5 of the remaining files and remove the other five from future consideration, because you have identified a group of files. Likewise, when you remove all files that have a common substring longer than the one they share with the target file, you've identified a group and you can process it as one instead of just throwing it back into the sea for future identification.

Comment: +1 on changing the ambiguous file-naming scheme. I've implemented [solution similar to your "different approach" part](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14728052/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: by "definition problem", I didn't actually mean to change the ambiguous file-naming scheme, I meant to think very hard about what is going to come up in practice, and write an accurate description that will define it for the purposes of this program. Of course, changing the scheme to be less ambiguous would be preferable provided that all the things creating these files can realistically be updated to follow a common scheme.

Comment: Given that the script intended **to remove** files; "less ambiguous" might be not good enough. If the scheme can't be changed; I'd use a series of simple narrow regexes that target a subset of files e.g., `^(\d{14})_(truck\d+)_\d+\.zip$` (validating `\d{14}` part with `datetime.strptime()`) and add incrementally more regexes looking at files that are not deleted in time.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: even if the format is somewhat ambiguous, you can write code to follow some algorithm like this and err on the side of assuming files are in different groups whenever it's doubtful. I'm assuming that incorrectly leaving files behind isn't a tragedy, but incorrectly deleting files is. But you're right, the sure-fire solution is to manually identify groups, and just say that until a group has been added to the list, files from it won't get deleted ever. You could send nagmail to someone: "the server is 80% full and there are 10784 report files not part of any deletion group".

Answer (score 1):

> The only predictable thing/pattern about the files is the files always contain a yyyymmddhhmmss timestamp somewhere and some pattern that repeats

To allow `yyyymmddhhmmss` anywhere in a filename and to find repeating patterns automatically you could first remove `yyyymmddhhmmss` from filename and then use the longest prefix that repeats at least twice as a repeating pattern.

```
import os
from itertools import groupby
from os.path import commonprefix

def files_to_delete(topdir):
    for rootdir, dirs, files in os.walk(topdir):
        # find files with yyyymmddhhmmss
        files_with_date = []
        for filename in files:
            for m in re.finditer(r"(?:^|\D)(\d{14})(?:\D|$)", filename):
                date = parse_date(m.group(1))
                if date is not None: # found date in the filename
                   # strip date
                   no_date = filename[:m.start(1)] + filename[m.end(1):]
                   # add to candidates for removal
                   files_with_date.append((no_date, date, filename))
                   break

        # find repeating pattern
        files_with_date.sort() # sort by filename with a removed date
        # given ["team1-a", "team2-b", "team2-c"]
        # yield [["team1-a"], ["team2-b", "team2-c"]] where 
        #    roots are "team1" and "team2"
        # reject [["team1-a", "team2-b", "team2-c"]] grouping (root "team")
        #     because the longer root "team2" occurs more than once
        roots = [commonprefix(a[0],b[0]) for a,b in pairwise(files_with_date)]
        roots.sort(key=len, reverse=True) # longest roots first
        def longest_root(item):
            no_date = item[0]
            return next(r for r in roots if no_date.startswith(r)) or no_date
        for common_root, group in groupby(files_with_date, key=longest_root):
            # strip 5 newest items (sort by date)
            for _, d, filename in sorted(group, key=lambda item: item[1])[:-5]:
                if d < month_ago: # older than 30 days
                   yield os.path.join(rootdir, filename)
```

Note: `['team1-a', 'team2-b', 'team3-c', ...]` are grouped together `[['team1-a', 'team2-b', 'team3-c', ...]]` using `'team'` as a repeating pattern i.e., the above algorithm fails if "repeating pattern" doesn't repeat in the file list.

Utilities:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from itertools import izip, tee

month_ago = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=30)

def parse_date(yyyymmddhhmmss):
    try: return datetime.strptime(yyyymmddhhmmss, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    except ValueError:
         return None

def pairwise(iterable): # itertools recipe
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

To remove a file you could call `os.remove(path)` instead of `os.system()`.

If you can then change the naming scheme of your files in the future to be more deterministic e.g., use `[]` around the pattern in a filename then you could extract root as:

```
root = re.match(r'[^[]*\[([^]]+)\]', filename).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

- Search the files until you come across one whose name contains 14 digits in a row.
- Check if these digits can be a timestamp.
- Search for all other files whose names contain the same remainder.
- Sort them in descending order of their date.
- Delete all files which are older than 5 days starting with the 6th file in the ordered file list.

Comment: the remainder contains random suffix i.e., the remainders can be different for files within the same group.

Comment: How do you know which files belong to one group? Is it only because they were saved at the same time but on different days? If that is the case search the other files of one group by searching for equal time codes in their filenames. However, is it possible that files within different groups have the same time code in their filenames?

Comment: *part* of the remainder is the same within a group. See [Steve Jessop's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14725728/4279).

Answer (score 0):

If the random part before `.zip` always consists of numbers and underscores, you could use this regex

```
(\d{14})_(.*?)[_\d]+\.zip
```

The first group in a match is a possible date, which you can check and parse using `datetime.datetime.strptime`. The second group is the constant part you use for grouping.

Answer (score 0):

This function will convert your filenames with a date stamp to an epoch time
It doesn't use regexp
You have to `import time`somewhere

```
def timestamp2epoch(str):
   x=[]
   for v in (str[0:4],str[4:6],str[6:8],str[8:10],str[10:12],str[12:14],0,0,0):
     x.append(int(v))
   return time.mktime(x)
```

Comment: Don't do this. Don't call your parameter `str` (hiding built-in type) and don't manually. Thus, you don't get an error when calling `timestamp2epoch("20129999999999_")`. Better extract a datetime, calculate timedelta to epoch and then get `total_seconds`. But: to have something that can be sorted, you don't need an integer, `datetime`-objects can be sorted as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just separate the problem out have one method find patterns, the other find dates and delete stuff

```
import os
import subprocess

def find_patterns():
    filenames = os.walk("/path/to/my/data/dir").next()[2]
    parsed_patterns = map(lambda file: "_".join(file.split("_")[1:-1]),filenames)
    unique_patterns = list(set(parsed_patterns))
    return unique_patterns

def delete_dates_after_past_five_days(unique_patterns):
    filenames = os.walk("/path/to/my/data/dir").next()[2]
    for pattern in unique_patterns:
        matched_files = filter(lambda file: pattern in file, filenames)
    sorted_files = sorted(matched_files) #Will sort by date
    if len(sorted_files) > 5:
        for file in sorted_files[:-5]:
            subprocess.call(["rm", os.path.join("/path/to/my/data/dir", file)])

unique_patterns = find_patterns()
delete_dates_from_past_five_days(unique_patterns)
```